# yii2 gridview filter on related column

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have joined 2 tables on my model search with

```
$query = Surveys::find()->select('surveys.*,regions.name AS region_name, published.description as published_name');
        $query->joinWith(['region']);
        $query->joinWith(['published0']);
```

I have now added sorting for the 2 extra columns

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
                'name',
                'description',
                'survey_type',
                'published_name' => [
                    'asc' => ['published.description' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['published.description' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Published',
                    'default' => SORT_ASC
                ],
                'region_name' => [
                    'asc' => ['regions.name' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['regions.name' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Region'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

I am not sure how to do filtering for these 2 columns. following is what i have

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([
            'survey_id' => $this->survey_id,
            'published' => $this->published,
            'date_added' => $this->date_added,
            'total_length' => $this->total_length,
            'region_id' => $this->region_id,
            'shrink' => $this->shrink,
            'country_id' => $this->country_id,
            'region_name' => $this->region_name,
            'published_name' => $this->published_name
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'guid', $this->guid])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'year_acquired', $this->year_acquired])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'year_processed', $this->year_processed])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'survey_type', $this->survey_type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'processing_type', $this->processing_type])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'center_point', $this->center_point])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'regions.name', $this->region_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'published.description', $this->published_name]);
```

I have also included the public variables in the `Surveys` model

```
 public $region_name;
     public $published_name;
```

On my `gridview` the 2 columns appear and i can sort them however there is no input box for filtering. how can i filter this?

Comment: Any validation rules for these attributes ?

Answer (score 1):

The variables must be filtered trough at least one rule.

Try adding this to your *search model*:

```
rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        [['region_name', 'published_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html):

> When this property is set, the grid view will enable column-based filtering. Each data column by default will display a text field at the top that users can fill in to filter the data.
>
> Note that in order to show an input field for filtering, a column must have its yii\grid\DataColumn::$attribute property set or have yii\grid\DataColumn::$filter set as the HTML code for the input field.
>
> When this property is not set (null) the filtering feature is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your search model class

In the rules() method, add a rule for your 2 fields so they'd be white listed when the search form is submitted as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798569/19469415
Or you can declare them safe as well

```
[['region_name', 'published_name'], 'safe']
```

In your search() method, remove the 2 fields in your exact match filter if you intend to search them via wild card method.

```
$query->andFilterWhere([

    ...

    'region_name' => $this->region_name, //remove this
    'published_name' => $this->published_name //remove this
]);
```